# toggleClass is not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

when the mouse is entering on the link or hover over the link, the link will get in a bold state and when the mouse is leaving the link it goes back to its normal state, but this is not happening as the **toggleClass** is not working

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
        <style>
            .bold{
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .normal{
                font-weight: normal;
            }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#">Link</a>

    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Bind.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').bind('mouseenter mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('bold');
    });
});
```

Comment: works for me https://jsfiddle.net/fxabnk4o/23/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("a").hover(
   function() {
      $( this ).addClass("bold").removeClass("normal");
   }, function() {
      $( this ).addClass("normal").removeClass("bold");
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just bold on hover you want to achieve JS is quite overkill just use plain old CSS

```
a:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: I know this but I am new to jQuery so that is why I am learning various event handling methods

Answer (score 0):

Looks like works fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').bind('mouseenter mouseleave',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('bold');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
        <style>
            .bold{
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .normal{
                font-weight: normal;
            }
        </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="#">Link</a>

    <script src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Bind.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But @Maantje is right, if you just want to apply `bold` on `hover`, you better just use CSS.

Comment: I know that CSS would be fine, but i m in learning cure of jQuery.. by the way thanx

Comment: @Dipanshu, what is `<script src="Bind.js"></script>`? Does your code (where you toggle bold) works without it? May there are some issues with "Bind.js" and "jQuery" together?

Comment: <script src="Bind.js"> is the jQuery File Extension in HTML  @Commercial Suicide

Comment: @Dipanshu, did you try to comment this script and run code without it? I think there is an issue with Bind.js, because in snippet and jsfiddle code works fine

Comment: The actual jQuery code is in the Bind.js file... never the less I think the toggleClass has some issues

Comment: @Dipanshu, ah, understand now